# How can I write a variadic template class?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic

To my understanding variadic functions are functions that take a variable number of arguments.

Now I would like to apply this to a template function for which I want the constructor to be a variadic one. I don't know if this is possible and how I can accomplish this. My questions are therefore:
Is it possible?
And how can I do that?

Here is my non-variadic template class. I want to be able to have varying number of placeholder parameters T (so either T1 only, or T1, T2 or maybe T1 to T5).

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
    class tXmlBase
    {
    public:
        tXmlBase(tXmlDoc* doc, T1 id1);
        tXmlBase(tXmlDoc* doc, T1 id1, T2 id2);

        virtual ~tXmlBase();
    protected:
        tXmlDoc* xml_doc;

        pugi::xml_node root_node;
        pugi::xml_node base_node;
        pugi::xml_node parent_node;

        T1 identifier1;
        T2 identifier2;

        int n_childs;
        int n_attr;
```

I've read this but I am not sure how to translate this to my class: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

EDIT: For better clarity:
The purpose of this is following:
This class shall handle the information stored inside a specific node of a xml-file. Let's assume following xml-file structure:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <elem id="1">
            <low_level_info type="info" content="abc"/>
            <low_level_info type="info" content="xyz" />
        </elem>
        <elem id="2">
            ...
        </elem>
     <node>
     <node>
        ...
     </node>
</root>
```

So some nodes are just nodes and differentiated only by being on the second position after the previous occurance of the node of same name (here "name"), others are differentiated by one or more attributes (id, content, type).

And I'd like my class to be capable to handle that I have different ways to differentiate these nodes.

Comment: You can write constuctors that take T1 or/and T2 with your class template parameters, but what would T3...5 correspond to ? New template parameters ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. In fact I'd like to create a class that depending on my xml-file schema may need constructors that need to use variable attribute values to identify the correct node when instantiating it. I will edit my question in order to make this clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no way to create a variadic data member, you'll have to use a `std::tuple`. The rest is pretty straightforward:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class tXmlBase
{
public:
    tXmlBase(tXmlDoc* doc, Ts const&... id1);

    // if you have no other virtual member, it's better to remove this.
    virtual ~tXmlBase();
protected:
    tXmlDoc* xml_doc;

    pugi::xml_node root_node;
    pugi::xml_node base_node;
    pugi::xml_node parent_node;

    std::tuple<Ts...> identifiers;

    int n_childs;
    int n_attr;
};
```

If you want to do something for all identifiers, you can use a variadic lambda and `std::apply`:

```
std::apply(
    [](auto&... id) {
        // expands into (id1.something(), id2.something(), ...)
        (id.something(), ...);
    },
    identifiers
);
```

Comment: Wow, that looks like expert programming. I will check out this. Thank you a lot, Guillaume!

Comment: The syntax is intimidating at first, but once you understand how the variadic expansion works, it's pretty straightforward

Comment: @ManyQuestions Note that my second example uses C++17 feature. Emulating that in C++14 is harder but possible.

Comment: The second part of your anser does it mean an array is generated that contains the return values of the respective ```something()``` functions? And if I want to get first code part to work with second code part should I consistently use ```id``` for both parts instead of ```id1``` in upper part and ```id``` in lower part? Sorry for so ManyQuestions - I am a C++ beginner.

Comment: @ManyQuestions No array is constructed. I'm simply using the comma operator to drop the result. If you want to put them in an array, simply `auto results = std::array{id.something()...}`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. I admit I am not quite sure what you are exactly doing here with the brackets ```[]``` and also what the function of ```auto&``` is but that's of course due to my incomplete knowledge of C++.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229770/discussion-between-guillaume-racicot-and-manyquestions).